# angular: how to nest templates inside <pre> tags?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, pre

does anyone know how do I do ng-include from within a 'pre' tag? The usecase is that I have a website with some code blocks and some of the code blocks contain common code that I want to move to a separate partial. Example:

```
<pre>
    My page-specific code....
    <ng-include src="'partials/common-code.html'"></ng-include>
</pre>
```

Needless to say, this does not work, as the ng-include tag appears literally in the output...

Answer (score 2):

You can do with a two directives: one is a sort of ngInclude, the other waits for the first to load the content and replaces itself with a `pre` (http://plnkr.co/edit/fPy4M0ZK94erF31EeObE):

```
module.directive('myPre', function() {
  return {
    controller: function() {},
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      controller.checkContent = function() {
        if (!element.children().length) {
          element.replaceWith('<pre>' + element.text() + '</pre>');
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
.directive('myPreTemplate', function($http) {
  return {
    require: '^myPre',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, myPre) {
      $http.get(attrs.src).then(function(res) {
        element.replaceWith(res.data);
        myPre.checkContent();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And you can use it like here:

```
<my-pre>
  Code here...
  <my-pre-template src="common.html"></my-pre-template>
  ...and here...
  <my-pre-template src="common.html"></my-pre-template>
  ...and here again
</my-pre>
```

**EDIT**: to render the content of common template, the best way is using [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) ([plunker updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/fPy4M0ZK94erF31EeObE)):

```
...
$http.get(attrs.src).then(function(res) {
  var rendered = Mustache.render(res, scope);
  element.replaceWith(rendered);
  myPre.checkContent();
});
...
```

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to test your code, but I have an issue: I expect common.html to also be a template. However, the code above will not bind any {{xxx}} tokens in common.html to the scope. How do I fix that?

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but mustache will render the template, however, if the common template also contains a <my-pre-template> nested inside it, mustache won't help.. right?

Comment: No it won't. If the thing gets too complex, I would do that statically with a templating engine

Comment: I was able to use $compile to get {{xx}} to be resolved in the my-pre-template... however, if I put another my-pre-template inside the common.html file, I get an error that the internal my-pre-template cannot compile since it requires myPre controller... I thought it would find one because of how the page is eventually built (i.e. my-pre at the top level)...

Comment: resolved using a BFS, added a new answer + plunkr below

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it based on your idea of using a top-level custom pre directive, but using a different impl: I'm running a BFS algorithm, where each digest cycle I try to compile any direct sub pre-includes. Every iteration I wait until the inclusion children count is zero before checking if we need another cycle (using scope.$watch). Once done, I compile the entire my-pre to resolve any {{xxxx}} and convert it to pre. [Working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4AI2or8Ltn1zrvoPwqjX)

```
// simulate a 3d party highligther (tested with HLJS)
.directive('myHighlighter', function($compile, $timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function() {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          // wait for the end of the digest:
          $timeout(function() {
          $(element).replaceWith($('<pre>' + element.text() + '</pre>'));
         });
        }
      }
})

// myPre will conert itself to the custom highlighter once done compiling:
.directive('myPre', function($compile, $timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function() {},
        link: { 
          pre: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          // limit the total inclusions allowed to avoid loops:
          scope.it = 100;
          // count inclusions:
          scope.incCount = 0;

            scope.$watch('incCount', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
              if (oldVal !== newVal && newVal === 0) {
                  // watch the include tag count. When it's zero,
                  // see if we need another BFS pass for sub-children:
                var children = $('pre-include', element).length;
              if (children !== 0) {
                $compile(element)(scope);
              } else {
                  // If not, build the highlighter and we're done:
                var e2 = $('<my-highlighter>' + element.html() + '</my-highlighter>');
                $(element).replaceWith(e2);
                $compile(e2)(scope);
              }
              }
            }); 
          },
          post: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) { 
          }
        }
      }
})

.directive('preInclude', function($templateRequest, $compile) {
  return {
    link: { 
      pre: function(scope, element, attrs, myPre) {
          scope.incCount++;
      }, 
      post: function(scope, element, attrs, myPre, transclude) {
        scope.it--;
        if (scope.it <= 0) {
          console.log("max iterations reached, stopping");
          return;
        }
        // enqueue the inclusion in the BFS queue:
        $templateRequest(attrs.src).then(function(data) {
          element.replaceWith(data);
          scope.incCount--;
        });
      }
    }
  };
})
```