# AngularJS 1 include preformated html code from templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm writing a tutorial website for angularjs using angularjs and I have a lot sections of sample code. 
So I have a bunch of `<pre>&lt;html ng-app&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</pre>` tags.

I want to put the code samples in a separate files but `ng-include` doesn't work on `<pre></pre>` tags. How would I put html code samples in separate files?

Small side question: what would you name the folder of those files? Would `./samples/` work?

I've tried this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34164921/859082

But it doesn't seem to work because the sample doesn't stay preformatted for newlines and tabs and I don't know why it doesn't work. Here's my attempt using the previous solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0nP76Im6XWWCleShsxAR?p=preview

Comment: Still looking for an answer for the folder name. Would ./samples/ work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your plunker, and came up with this [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xr21St1mRZqvbDdrUlX9). You could dynamically set the path, which would update the content.

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <pre ng-bind="content"></pre>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**JS**

```
angular
  .module('app', [])

  .controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,$http,$log){

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'common1.html'
    }).then(function successCallback(resp) {
        $scope.content = resp.data;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        $log.warn('Could not locate file...');
      });

  });
```

**Additional Plunks:**

1. Allow changing template that is displayed (change index to common1): http://plnkr.co/edit/s5N1nhYQ6SnJ7SVKHVas?p=preview
2. View page's own code: http://plnkr.co/edit/hJm0b4SQzPTSeRrGmYCx?p=preview
3. Multiple samples per page: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtyp6xL1BViicoFUVOSb?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, @WorkWe provided a solution for me. Would you say your solution is a better design? If so, why?

Comment: I would say that it is a better design, first and foremost because it allows you to write the included content as you would an actual HTML file. In this sample, it can load itself as the content: http://plnkr.co/edit/hJm0b4SQzPTSeRrGmYCx?p=preview. This will allow you to create and edit the included files with greater ease. Secondarily, I always shoot for simplicity, and in this case, it does not require any additional dependencies, and minimalizes required code to complete.

Comment: Also, I believe that if your goal is to dynamically set the file to load, it would be easier to handle this within the controller vs. having to create a function to change the template url in the directive.

Comment: I've added the plunker from above, and one other to the answer to demonstrate changing the template using a simple input field/button.

Comment: This is a great solution for my problem, I'm making the website as I'm learning the AngularJS 1 framework. Unfortunately, at this time I haven't learned jQuery or Mustache yet, so I don't fully understand your solution yet. I will definitely use it in the future when I do learn those frameworks.

Comment: I'm actually not using either, I hadn't removed them from the script tags. It looks like your original plunk was using Mustache in the directives however. I am just using straight Angular with my examples.

Comment: :) No problem. I try to avoid pulling in other libraries as much as possible. It can start to get messy, especially if you are ever looking to write tests.

Comment: How would you implement this for multiple code samples on one page?

Comment: Just added a new plunker with how I would do it: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtyp6xL1BViicoFUVOSb?p=preview. You could store the entire page in an array, eventually having some or all of that data come from a backend source.

Comment: Hmm, can you bind the paths to models not using a loop? That way you don't have to use a ng-repeat and just display models arbitrarily on the page.

Comment: So ng-bind="samples[1].content" works, how do I change that so I don't need to use array indexes?

Comment: Also, can you define your foreach function non-anonymously so it could be used over multiple controllers?

Answer (score 2):

Set CSS `white-space: pre-wrap;` for your `myPre` directive.

Comment: Thanks! I'm so frustrated that this took 4 hours to find out. Should of posted here sooner. Solution http://plnkr.co/edit/0nP76Im6XWWCleShsxAR?p=preview